# Passing collections of derived objects in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, collections

I'm still getting my feet wet with OO and C#. I'm sure this is a simple question and I think I know the answer, but I want to be sure.

If I have a class called `Car` and another class called `Ford` which inherits from `Car`, and yet another class called `Mustang` which inherits from the `Ford` class.

Is it acceptable/possible to create a method that accepts a collection of `Car` objects and then when I call that method actually pass to that method a collection of `Mustang` (or `Ford`) objects since they are in fact `Car` objects?

My thought is that this should be possible, with the understanding that I would only be able to access Properties\Methods of the `Car` class.  Am I way off base on this?

Also, if I am right, that you can do this: do you need to cast the `Mustang` collection to a `Car` collection in the call to the method?

Answer (score 5):

No, that's not possible.

So if we have a function that accepts a `List<Car>` types.  Clearly that function ought to be able to add a `Prius` to that list, no?  Well, if you were allowed to pass a `List<Mustang>` to this method you'd have just added a `Prius` to a `List<Mustang>`, clearly that would be bad.

Now if, rather than passing a `List`, the method had a parameter of `IEnumerable` or one of certain other read only collection types then it's possible it's "covariant".  In that case, you could accept, as an example, an `IEnumerable<Car>` and pass it a `List<Mustang>` because you're never adding to the list, you're only accessing various elements, and as long as all of the `Mustang` objects are `Car` objects that's not a problem.

The design also seems a bit...off.  I wouldn't think that `Ford` should inherit from `Car`.  `Ford` isn't a car, it's a brand, a company, a type of car.  `Mustang` **is a** car, so it makes sense for it to inherit from one.  I would create a new type, say `Manufacturer` of which you could create `Ford`, `Toyota`, etc. and make that a (read only) property of `Car`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer, but if `Prius` inherits from `Car`, and `Mustang` inherits from `Car`, then you would be able to add a `Prius` or `Mustang` to a list of type `Car`.

Comment: @Matthew Yes, you should, and can.  But if you passed a `List<Mustang>` to a method that has a parameter of `List<Car>` then you could add a `Prius` to it, thus the end result is a `List<Mustang>` with a `Prius` in it.  That would be bad.  However, you **can't** pass a `List<Mustang>` to a method accepting a `List<Car>`.  This is merely explaining why.

Comment: Maybe my question is better served like this... I want to create a method that will accept a collection of a base type of object (Car)... I don't care what type of Car it is... I just want it to accept a list of objects that are of type Car (Mustang, Prius, Corvette, etc).  Then in my method, I can process each car generically, but also be able to tell what type of car it is, so that if it is in fact a Prius I can tell it to do something else as well.  Make sense?

Comment: @BMT The question is whether you have your Mustangs in a Mustang list or a Car list. You probably have them in a Mustang list, and it's probably right that way, and you probably need to accept `IEnumerable<Car>` instead of `List<Car>`, which then solves everything.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already explained various aspects of sending a collection of Mustangs as a parameter to a different method, then I'll just add in a little info which you might find useful as well.

If you have a collection of Cars `List<Car>` you can get only the Mustangs out of it by:

```
IEnumerable<Mustang> mstngs = cars.OfType<Mustang>();
List<Mustang> mstngsLst = mstngs.ToList();
```

And if you have a collection of Mustangs `List<Mustang>` you can cast them all into cars with:

```
IEnumerable<Car> cars = mstngs.Cast<Car>();
List<Car> carsLst = cars.ToList();
```

Converting back into a list is not a must, by the way. It depends on what you need to do with the collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only going to access methods and properties in the `Car` class there is no reason to pass a list of `Mustangs`. Instead you should just deal with your `Mustangs` as if they were `Cars`. That's one of the main points of inheritance. You can simply create a list of type car `List<Car>` then add your `Mustangs` to it. Then pass the list of type `Car`. This is more extensible because it can accept any object which inherits from `Car` and since you're only using properties/methods from `Car` it's as strict of a definition as you need.

If you want specific behavior in the `Mustang` class but a common interface for invoking that behavior define the method in `Car` then override it in `Mustang`. Again, this is more extensible because when you create a `NineEleven` class you can also override this method thus giving you different behavior in the child classes without actually exposing their type.

Comment: It's not right to always assume he'll want to have lists of cars instead of lists of some sort of derived type.  It often makes sense to have a collection of a somewhat more derived type.

Comment: @Servy Yes, but if you're dealing strictly with a derived type then you should have a method that is strictly for that derived type or should be invoking a method which is overloaded in the derived type.

Comment: Again, not something I agree with.  If you have a collection of a derived type you shouldn't *only* need to pass it to a method accepting a collection of a derived type, at least conceptually.  There are limitations on what you can do in practice.  The underlying concept here is "covariance", and C# has implemented it (to a degree).

Comment: @Servy That's fine but it's strictly opinion. I do see value in using IEnumerables but not in this case. Simple problems deserve simple solutions.

Comment: What's complex about using an `IEnumerable`?  Also keep in mind that the problem has the feel of not being practical, the purpose is to teach the OP how to properly design a project, thus one should propose solutions in line with good design, rather than something that "just works" but isn't as extensible or preferable in a larger scaled application.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, passing a `List<Car>` containing a `Ford`:s for example:

```
public void Test()
{
    // This works:
    var fords = new List<Car> {new Ford()};
    FixCars(fords);

    // This does not work (since you cannot pass non car-typed list):
    // var mustangs = new List<Ford> {new Ford()};
    // FixCars(fords);
}

public void FixCars(List<Car> cars)
{
    // Do stuff, for example check actual type and do specialized things:
    foreach (var car in cars)
    {
        var ford = car as Ford;
        if (ford != null)
            ford.Honk();
    }
}

public class Car 
{    
}

public class Ford : Car
{
    public void Honk() {}
}
```

Comment: Now see what happens when you try to call `FixCars` on a `List<Mustang>`.  You'll see it won't work.  Why is that?  (That's basically the question the OP is asking.)

Comment: @YoryeNathan From the OP: `"when I call that method actually pass to that method a collection of Mustang"`

Comment: @Servy: Yes, you are right, but it is a bit unclear (to me) if the OP meant a `List<Mustang>` or a `List<Car>` filled with Mustang objects. "...a collection of Mustang (or Ford) objects..". Anyway, wanted to show how it needs to be coded to work (at least similar) to what was asked.

Comment: I was thinking that you were showing a different way, actually, of really HAVING a collection of cars filled with mustangs... Which is why I didn't understand @Servy your first comment.